# C# cryptosystem .NET API interface with C

Tags: c#, c, cryptography, cryptoapi

I am looking to implement the C# Cryptosystem .NET api with C code, so i am wondering what a possible at best route would be?

I have currently begun looking at this link below.

http://libtom.org/?page=features&whatfile=crypt

I am wondering if it would be possible to use my own public and private keys for decoding(in C) already encrypted data(done in C#) with this library?

Anyone got some advice on past experience with this type of procedure?

Comment: Yes. Don't. Use OpenSSL instead, maybe add a .net compatible wrapper around it.

Comment: Hey Owlstead, thanks for the advice. Did not even know what OpenSSL was until you mentioned it. I am confused on the second part of your comment however, "maybe add a .net compatible wrapper around it". What exactly do you mean?                                                                                  For more exact information I am using [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.dsacryptoserviceprovider_methods(v=vs.71) and i have to essentially do the VerifyData method in C. Hope this helps any further description!

Comment: What i meant whas that although openssl should provide almost any functionality required, you may need to add some functionality to it, or you could wrap it to look more like the C# API (eg regarding encoding). Should I post my previous comment as an answer?

Comment: What do you actually need to do? .NET and the windows CNG and CAPI crypto api's do a lot of things and for average uses, its not likely you need to go further?

Comment: @imichaelmiers I need to Basically do the VerifyData method from the DSACryptoServiceProvider class in C, using an ANSI C compiler. [link]http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.dsacryptoserviceprovider.verifydata(v=vs.71)

Comment: @owlstead your comment makes sense now, I am going to give this a go.